# Foreign Keys In MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, jsp-tags

I'm building a simple web-based application for school purposes that should enable certain users to buy certain products they choose from a dropdown menu. Whenever a user clicks to buy a product they chose from a dropdown menu this product gets stored into a purchased items table and at the same time gets removed from another table called products. From what I know, in order to be able to do this I would need to have 3 tables: users, products, purchase and in the purchase table I should have 2 columns with foreign keys that is #1 for the   purchaser and #2 for the product purchased. I thought I resolved this issue but my glassfish server keeps throwing the following error at me:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>    Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>    (`webprodaja`.`kupljeno`, CONSTRAINT `kupljeno_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

Ok, here are the tables and foreign keys in question:

Table 'users':

```
id | name
1  | Ivan
2  | Beka
3  | Ogi
```

Table 'proizvodi' (eng. products):

```
id | name
1  | kafa
2  | jafa
3  | ratluk
```

Table 'kupljeno' (eng. purchase):

```
id | name | proizvod
2  | Beka | 3
3  | Ogi  | 2
```

Table 'kupljeno' also has 2 foreign keys:

One that was put on the 'id' column and references the table 'users' and its column 'id';

Another one that was put on the 'proizvod' column and references the table 'proizvodi' and its column 'id';

So what I'm trying to do is delete whichever product a buyer chose and get its name deleted in the 'proizvod' column and therefore put the same product into the 'kupljeno' column. However, I was able to make a purchase and store the details into 'kupljeno' column but for some reason I can't do this any longer let alone delete the product being bought in the 'proizvod' column.

Also, here's the complete index.jsp code for what it's worth:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
        <body>


    <%


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webprodaja","root","");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
       // if(request.getParameter("add")!=null){

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users");
            %>
            <form action="index.jsp" method="post">  
            <select name="user">

                <%
                while(rs.next())
                   {
                    String name=rs.getString(2);
                    String id = rs.getString(1);
                %>

                <option  value="<%=name%>" ><%=name%></option>

                <%
                   }
                %>

            </select> 

                <%

                ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select * from proizvodi");

                %>

                <select name="proizvod">

                <%
                while(rs1.next())
                   {
                    String name1=rs1.getString(2);
                    String id1 = rs1.getString(1);
                %>

                <option value="<%=id1%>" ><%=name1%></option>

                <%
                   }
                %>

                </select> 
                <input type="submit" name="add" value="buy"/>
             </form>   


                <%

                if(request.getParameter("add")!=null)
                {
                    String user = request.getParameter("user");
                    String proizvod = request.getParameter("proizvod"); 
                    st.execute("insert into kupljeno(id, name, proizvod) values (null, '"+user+"', "+proizvod+")");

                }

                %>                                  


        <%-- <form action="index.jsp" method="post">
           <input type="submit" name="add" value="buy">

       </form> --%>    


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the reason for deleting the product from the products table?

Comment: I want to put a bought product from the table 'proizvodi' into the table 'kupljeno' and then get rid of the bought product so it looks like it has been purchased and is no longer available.
How do I copy a product's ID and store it in the referencing column in the 'kupljeno' table and then delete that value in 'proizvodi' table?

Comment: so, when one user purchases a product, is it then no longer available for any other users to purchase? because this would be the effect.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: why not do stock column inside product table and then when unit has 0 stock it is not available for purchase and when there is one stock it is available for purchase. Then when one is purchased the stock is reduced by the amount of stock purchased.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it simple without having to track down the stock product. I have a hunch that a simple and neat code would resolve this issue in no time, I just need to figure out which one.

Comment: then take out the foreign key check back to the products table and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

you stated,

> and at the same time gets removed from another table called products

and also you said,

> table 'kupljeno'[purchase] also has 2 foreign keys:
>   one that was put on the 'id' column and references the table 'users' and its column 'id';
>   another one that was put on the 'proizvod'[product] column and references the table 'proizvodi'[product] and its column 'id';

When a table's row has a fk constraint to another table's row, then the second table's row cannot be deleted until the first table's row is deleted. You should read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) article about foreign key constraints.

Why do this? It is bad design. Do not remove from products table.

Instead control this with your code to prevent users from purchasing the same product twice if desired. Do not force MySQL to do what it shouldn't; make your code do what it should!

Comment: As stated, this is for my school project that provided clear guidelines. Take the item from 'proizvodi' table and put it into 'kupljeno' table so it looks like the purchase has been made. I need to play around the code so it removes certain rows and stores them into another column. How do I achieve this?

Comment: remove the foreign key from the purchases table to the products table and then you should be able to insert into purchased table and delete from products table

Comment: OK, I solved the problem partially, GlassFish is not throwing an error any more and the data gets stored into the binding 'kupljeno' table. What I now and still want to do is remove items from 'proizvodi' and put them into the 'kupljeno' table.

Comment: Could this be a misinterpretation of the assignment? "Take" the product from the products table perhaps means to use its ID for the insert, not to delete the entire row from the table? For the most obvious way to code this, I think, would be to add a where clause to the select for the products, specifying that they should not yet be present in the purchase table. `SELECT * FROM proizvodi WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM kupljeno WHERE kupljeno.proizvod = proizvodi.id)` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71177d/1 If you think this is not the solution, can you give a more precise wording of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide the value for that foreign key column (rather oddly named `id`, rather than `users_id`, in the kupljeno table. And we usually add a primary key on every table, which this one does not seem to have.

```
insert into kupljeno(id, name, proizvod) values (null, '"+user+"', "+proizvod+")"
                     ^^                          ^^^^
```

I suspect that you have declared the id column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute in the `kupljeno` table, as if it were the primary key of the table, rather than a foreign key to another table.

The reason that I suspect that, because you are inserting a NULL value, but the row that is attempting to be inserted has a value. That's either being assigned because of an AUTO_INCREMENT attribute on the column, or (less likely in this case) it's being assigned by a trigger.

(What would go a long ways to actually identify the problem would be the ACTUAL TABLE DEFINTIONS, which can easily be obtained using a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement.)

What I think you really want is to separate the PRIMARY KEY of the table, from the FOREIGN KEY that references the `users` table, like this:

```
id          - primary key
user_id     - foreign key references user(id)
user_name   - (redundant, copied from user.name)
product_id  - foreign key to product(id)
```

Comment: The shuffled id values in the 'kupljeno.id' column stores whichever the id in the users/products tables are, it doesn't need to have a primary key, the purpose of this table is to show who bought what, not to put values in an ascending order. What i want to do is get rid of the value(s) in the 'proizvodi' table and put those same values in the 'kupljeno' table depending on what user bought which product. It should be easy enough but since I'm getting my feet wet into handling these issues I would need an idea on how to resolve this. I was told to go by the foreign key solution, anyone?

Comment: @Ivan Ćeličanin: you are assiging a NULL value to the id column in your insert statement. So, this should be a NULL in the table. But a NULL value wouldn't throw the exception you are getting. However, if an attempt to insert a row which had an id value which is NOT FOUND in the `users.id` column would throw that exception. As far as how to debug this, figure out the exact SQL text of the statement that is throwing the exception. The only statement I see in the code you posted that could be throwing the exception is the INSERT.